# listener на удаление элемента

Tags: javascript, html, события, listener

Существуют ли какой либо стандартный Event на удаление исчезновение элемента из DOM. Что-то типа:

```
document.getElementById("someId")
  .addEventListener("misticEventThanElRemove", someFunction);
```

Не знаю что вставить вместо misticEventThanElRemove.

Или подскажите как обработать исчезновение/удаление элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне известно, конкретно *события* нет, но есть, [`mutation observer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) - стандарт позволяющий следить за изменениями в `dom` дереве

Пример:

```js
// boilerplate для демонстрации
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');
const createBtn = document.getElementById('create');

const createLi = () => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = `Элемент списка ${ul.children.length + 1}`;
  
  ul.appendChild(li);
  if(deleteBtn.disabled) deleteBtn.disabled = false;
}
const deleteLi = () => {
  const li = ul.children[ul.children.length - 1];

  ul.removeChild(li);
  deleteBtn.disabled = !ul.children.length;
}

createBtn.onclick = createLi;
deleteBtn.onclick = deleteLi;

// А теперь добавим mutation observer
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if(mutation.addedNodes.length) console.log('Добавили элемент');
    else if(mutation.removedNodes.length) console.log('Удалили элемент');
  });
});
// Подписываем только на изменения дочернего дерева
const config = {childList: true};
observer.observe(ul, config);
```

```css
button {
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Элемент списка 1</li>
  <li>Элемент списка 2</li>
  <li>Элемент списка 3</li>
  <li>Элемент списка 4</li>
</ul>
<button id='delete'>Удалить элемент</button>
<button id='create'>Добавить</button>
```

Comment: [были но устарели :)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)